# Is it possible to name a function with the value of a Constant?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to do something like

```
public ActionResult Constants.MethodName()
{
return View();
}
```

Do you think is possible?

**Update**:
I would like this because I have some components of the application in the Client side that calls this method. So, If someday I want to rename the method all will be broken. If I use a constant I could rename it without problems.
`Constants` in the example is a shared library, a static class in a project that have all the constants of the solution.

`Constants` look like this

```
public static class Constants
{
    public const string MethodName = "MethodName";    
}
```

In the client side:

```
            HubConnection connection = new HubConnection(_hubUrl);
            IHubProxy proxy = connection.CreateHubProxy(Constants.MethodName);
            connection.Start().Wait();
```

Comment: In short: no, I don't.

Comment: I don't get it. Is `Constants` name of a class?

Comment: why would you need that?

Comment: Please Could you tell us the purpose please to doing that?

Comment: Well, If you emit IL you can certainly do this.

Comment: I Updated the question explaning why I think I need it.

Comment: This is utterly the wrong way of going about this. Why would you change the method name of an action? That is going to change all of your URLs. Even then, how does using a constant solve the problem? Please elaborate in your question.

Comment: @victor-mukherjee debugging, logging — compiler provided the current function name as a constant all the way to the 1980th for that reason. `__FUNCTION_NAME__` was the most common name.

Answer (score 5):

No, but I think you can achieve the result you're looking for by implementing an `interface` in a shared library, instead of referring to a `constant` in that library.

In the library shared by client and server:

```
public interface ISomeService
{
    SomeResult SomeAction();
}
```

On the server:

```
public SomeService : ApiController, ISomeService
{
    public SomeResult SomeAction() {...}
}
```

On the client:

```
SomeResult someResult = await serviceLayer.Invoke<ISomeService>(s => s.SomeAction());
```

A structure like this would allow you to rename the service method on the interface, and have it renamed in your client and server code automatically, using refactoring tools.

Comment: @AntP: I elaborated on it a bit. This approach would require some additional work, and some changes in some minor details from the OP, but it's at least reasonable to think it could be done.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MethodName()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and then:

```
Expression<Action<HomeController>> expression = (HomeController c) => c.MethodName();
string actionName = ((MethodCallExpression)expression.Body).Method.Name;

HubConnection connection = new HubConnection(_hubUrl);
IHubProxy proxy = connection.CreateHubProxy(actionName);
connection.Start().Wait();
```

Now you can Refactor->Rename your action as much as you want without breaking anything. There aren't any magic strings in the code and you don't need any constants or the obviously impossible `public ActionResult Constants.MethodName()` C# syntax.

And if your action was taking parameters, you could simply pass `default(ParameterType)` values in the expression call as the action is not called and the values don't matter.

Comment: I like a lot this approach. But... with this approach I would need that the client app have a reference to the web server side? Is this ok?

Comment: One possibility would be to abstract the actions into an interface that your controller will implement. Then put this interface into a third assembly that will be shared between the server and the client. This interface will represent a strong type between the 2.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class Constants
{
    public ActionResult ConstantName()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Is what I think you mean? Then you could access it via Constants.ConstantName()...

If you're worried about compatibility with clients after renaming the method, that's a common issue that all shared libraries face.

Your best bet if you wish to rename the method later is to simply keep the old function and return the value of the new function so that people using the old calling methods will still get the new method's return value. I.e.

```
public int Double(int i)
{
    return i * 2;
}
```

... some months later ...

```
[Obsolete("Use NewDouble instead.")]
public int Double(int i)
{
    return NewDouble(i);
}

public int NewDouble(int i)
{
    return i << 1;
}
```

**Edit**: Oh, I think I see what you mean. You want to be able to assign static names to functions that aren't actually reflected in your code? So if you reference a method called Whatever() in the client and change its name later to Whatever2(), the client can still reference the method because of its static name.

The only way I can think of for you to do that is to use Reflection. You could create an attribute with a unique identifier for each method, and then have the client use a Dictionary provided by the non-client-side, to retrieve a MethodInfo object for that method and then call the method with that.

**Edit again**: I implemented this to see if it would work, and it seems to well enough.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
sealed class MethodIDAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int ID { get; private set; }

    public MethodIDAttribute(int id)
    { this.ID = id; }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public static Dictionary<int, MethodInfo> MethodIDs = new Dictionary<int, MethodInfo>();

    static TestClass()
    {
        MethodInfo[] mi = typeof(TestClass).GetMethods();
        foreach (MethodInfo info in mi)
        {
            if (info.Name == "ToString" || info.Name == "Equals" || info.Name == "GetHashCode" || info.Name == "GetType")
            { continue; }
            int id = ((MethodIDAttribute)info.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(MethodIDAttribute))).ID;
            MethodIDs.Add(id, info);
        }
    }

    [MethodID(123456)]
    public int Double(int i)
    {
        return i * 2;
    }
}

public static class Constants
{
    public static class TestClass
    {
        public static int Double = 123456;
    }
}

public class ExampleCaller
{
    public int SomeMethod()
    {
        TestClass tc = new TestClass();
        return (int)TestClass.MethodIDs[Constants.TestClass.Double].Invoke(tc, new object[] { 10 });
    }
}
```

You might be able to simply create an abstract base class that your classes could inherit that could implement the MethodIDs Dictionary and its filling for them.

This solution is pretty ugly though...